# How to push local postgresql database built on rails to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, heroku

I have some data in my postgresql database that I entered using a very simple rails app. I deployed it to heroku and now am trying to send my local database to heroku because its very empty right now.
At first I thought doing `heroku run rake db:migrate` would actually do this but turns out it only creates tables in heroku?
These are the steps I took to transfer my local database to heroku.
1: `heroku run rake db:migrate` ( I did this to create tables which should be empty right?)
2: `heroku pg:push my_db DATABASE_URL --app my-herokuapp-98989` (the actual syntax to transfer database)
Here, it said 
"Remote database is not empty. Please create a new database or use `heroku pg:reset`"
4: `heroku pg:reset DATABASE`

> "WARNING: Destructive action"
>   "postgresql-amorphous-59192 will
>   lose all of its data"
>   "To proceed, type my-herokuapp-98989 or
>   re-run this command with --confirm my-herokuapp-98989

5: `my-herokuapp-98989`
"`Resetting postgresql-amorphous-59192... done`"
After this I try to open my app but it gives off an error saying

> "ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation
>   "drinks" does not exist"
>  "2017-07-29T04:50:20.697828+00:00
>   app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "drinks".* FROM "drinks""

"drinks" is the name of my table and I think it is giving this error because I just reset my database so there is no table or columns and rows?
So again I try pushing my database to heroku and it just freezes at this point
6:  `heroku pg:push my_db DATABASE_URL --app my-herokuapp-98989`
"`heroku-cli: Pushing my_db ---> postgresql-amorphous-59192`"
...and it freezes here
What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure it's freezing? or its just loading, because you need to upload the dumpfile to heroku.

you also can try this command

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://url/where/heroku/can/download/yourdbdump.dump' DATABASE_URL
```

more about import export you can read here. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import